# Is there a way to override the URI declared in a TLD of a tag library?

Tags: jsp, servlets, taglib

Say I'm using a tag library packaged in a JAR file. Given that I don't want to modify the JAR file, is there a way to change or override the declared URI of the tag library in case that its URI collides with another tag library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get conflicting URIs for different taglibs and don't want to change the JAR, you could extract the TLD from the JAR and try to overwrite it in `web.xml` with something like this:

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://foobar.org</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/yourtaglib.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

This assumes you placed the extracted TLD file in `/WEB-INF/tlds/yourtaglib.tld` and that you will refer to it with `http://foobar.org` in the JSPs:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://foobar.org" prefix="p" %>
```

Comment: is this behavior standard or specified anywhere in the specs? Will it work across different web servers?

Comment: @supertonsky: It is my understanding that what you define in web.xml takes precedence when resolving the taglib map. 
See for example the [JSP 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/), section JSP.7.3 (especially JSP.7.3.2). But I don't know how different servlet containers will react to this, and don't know if behavior will be uniform across implementations.